# Why is the border property not working on list item?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for asking such an easy question, but I'm stuck and the existing answers aren't working for me. I've boiled it down to the simplest case of a list but I can't get borders to show.

```css
html,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
p,
ol,
ul,
li,
a {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
}


/* feed styling */

.feed ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.feed ul li {
  border: 10px single black;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="feed">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`border: 10px single black;`</s> is incorrect.

Use `border: 10px solid black;`

```css
html,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
p,
ol,
ul,
li,
a {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
}

.feed ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.feed ul li {
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="feed">
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @brownmagik352 Glad I could help out! Keep on coding! :)